# Python write string to CSV without quoting

Tags: python, csv, formatting

I have this snippet:

```
import csv
data_list = [
    {"id": 123, "raw_json": '{"project_id": 100, "name": "ABC", "created_at": "2020-06-27T15:23:09Z"}'},
    {"id": 456, "raw_json": '{"project_id": 200, "name": "XYZ", "created_at": "2018-06-27T15:23:09Z"}'}
]

### ^ NOTE: `raw_json` are JSON strings

with open("/tmp/test", "w") as outfile_fd:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        outfile_fd,
        fieldnames=["id", "raw_json"],
        delimiter="\t",
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    )
    for rowdict in data_list:
        writer.writerow(rowdict)
```

Now I examine the output file, `$ cat /tmp/test` , it shows

```
123     "{""project_id"": 100, ""name"": ""ABC"", ""created_at"": ""2020-06-27T15:23:09Z""}"
456     "{""project_id"": 200, ""name"": ""XYZ"", ""created_at"": ""2018-06-27T15:23:09Z""}"
```

How do I get rid of the quoting? Desired file looks like:

```
123     {"project_id": 100, "name": "ABC", "created_at": "2020-06-27T15:23:09Z"}
456     {"project_id": 200, "name": "XYZ", "created_at": "2018-06-27T15:23:09Z"}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without DictWriter

One advantage of the csv module is, that is handles quoting for you. If you don't want that, why use it at all?

```
with open("/tmp/test", "w") as outfile_fd:
    for rowdict in data_list:
        outfile_fd.write(f'{rowdict["id"]}\t{rowdict["raw_json"]}\n')
```

### With DictWriter

If you want to continue using the csv module, though, you can change the quotechar to something that is not in the string, for example:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(
        outfile_fd,
        fieldnames=["id", "raw_json"],
        delimiter="\t",
        quotechar="'",
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    )
```

The string got quoted, because it included the default [quotechar](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your input data 
**from:**

```
data_list = [
    {"id": 123, "raw_json": '{"project_id": 100, "name": "ABC", "created_at": "2020-06-27T15:23:09Z"}'},
    {"id": 456, "raw_json": '{"project_id": 200, "name": "XYZ", "created_at": "2018-06-27T15:23:09Z"}'}
]
```

**to:**

```
data_list = [
    {"id": 123, "raw_json": {"project_id": 100, "name": "ABC", "created_at": "2020-06-27T15:23:09Z"}},
    {"id": 456, "raw_json": {"project_id": 200, "name": "XYZ", "created_at": "2018-06-27T15:23:09Z"}}
]
```

After these changes, output is:
[image: sample output of script]

**OR**

You can use this updated code:

```
import csv
data_list = [
    {"id": 123, "raw_json": '{"project_id": 100, "name": "ABC", "created_at": "2020-06-27T15:23:09Z"}'},
    {"id": 456, "raw_json": '{"project_id": 200, "name": "XYZ", "created_at": "2018-06-27T15:23:09Z"}'}
]

### ^ NOTE: `raw_json` are JSON strings

with open("/tmp/test", "w") as outfile_fd:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        outfile_fd,
        fieldnames=["id", "raw_json"],
        delimiter="\t",
        quoting=0
    )
    for rowdict in data_list:
        try:
            rowdict['raw_json'] = eval(rowdict['raw_json'])
        except:
            pass
        writer.writerow(rowdict)
```

**Output:**
[image: sample output]

Comment: This single quoted output is not valid json anymore, if that was a requirement.

Comment: This is as per required output as defined by the author

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are speech marks in the string that is the value for `raw_json`, simply removing the quotation marks before inserting the raw_json into the csv will resolve this issue.

```
for rowdict in data_list:
        rowdict["raw_json"] = rowdict.get("raw_json").replace("\"", "")
        writer.writerow(rowdict)
```

Fixed it for me, the best way to resolve this is to not have the quotation marks in the JSON anyway as that dictionary is properly parsed JSON, but this solution works for the JSON you have provided.